# What does this "return unicode(self.creator) + " - " + self.title" do in Django?

Tags: python, django, forum

I am following a lightbird tutorial on creating a forum with Django/Python. Here is the code to create a `Thread` model.

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.creator) + " - " + self.title
```

And a `Post` model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s - %s - %s" % (self.creator, self.thread, self.title)

    def short(self):
        return u"%s - %s\n%s" % (self.creator, self.title, self.created.strftime("%b %d, %I:%M %p"))
    short.allow_tags = True
```

I am having difficulty understanding the code after the **unicode** function! I have been using the **unicode** while creating model in a very simple form like:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

I understand this but not the code in the models above. Could someone please explain it to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 unicode(self.creator) +\ #will call the __unicode__ method of the User class
 ' - ' +\ # will add a dash
 self.title #will add the title which is a string
```

then for the second one

```
  "%s"%some_var #will convert some_var to a string (call __str__ usually...may fall back on __unicode__ or something)
```

so

```
return u"%s - %s\n%s" % (self.creator, self.title, self.created.strftime("%b %d, %I:%M %p"))
```

will call the `__str__` (or maybe `__unicode__`)function on User class for the creator

then it adds a dash and the title

`\n` is an end line

and `strftime` will convert a timestamp into english "MonthAbbrv.  Day,  24Hr:Minutes"